# No vendor/autoload.php file in Laravel folder after installation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, xampp, composer-php

I am on Debian and I installed Laravel 5 in the htdocs folder of XAMPP using :
`sudo composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravel5`.

Then I started my Apache server using : `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`.

Then, I went to this address : http://localhost/laravel5/public

But I got this error :

> Warning: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel5/public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type in /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel5/public/index.php on line 24
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel5/public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel5/public/index.php on line 24

And indeed, there is no `vendor/autoload.php` file in the `laravel5` folder. Here is the tree of this folder:

```
laravel5
|-app
| |-...
|-artisan
|-bootstrap
|-composer.json
|-config
| |-...
|-database
| |-...
|-package.json
|-phpunit.xml
|-public
| |-...
|-package.json 
|-readme.md
|-resources
| |-...
|-routes
| |-...
|-server.php
|-storage
| |-...
|-tests
| |-...
|-webpack.mic.js
```

What did I do wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are all composer dependencies installed, is there `vendor/autoload.php` file existing?

Comment: No, in fact there are only these files in the `public` folder : css (folder containing app.js), favicon.ico, index.php,  js (folder containing app.js), robots.txt, web.config

Comment: Then you have to issue `composer install` command. Edit: not in public directory. In root directory of the application. It is one parent directory of `public`.

Comment: Yeah I changed my first post. I will try to reinstall it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP is running as `nobody:nogroup` by default, but you ran composer with your user.

You can do

`sudo chown -R nobody:nogroup /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel5`

to change the user and group.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I have a specific location to execute this command? I tried in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel5` but it didn't work. And the 2 commands I wrote won't execute without the `sudo`.

Comment: you should use sudo here too. i edited the answer.
starting the server requires sudo because you're not running it as a service and you might not have the correct permissions to execute `/opt/lampp/lampp`. you can fix that by following the instructions in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/870115

Comment: Thank you again but I don't think that's a matter of permissions because PHP is running well. The fact I should have mentioned is that there is no `vendor/autoload.php` file in the public folder indeed, and that makes me mad because I don't know why it didn't install properly. I added the tree of the folder in the first post.

Comment: Did you `composer install`? This is a weird question, i know, but since there's no vendor folder, it looks like it didn't run on create-project.

At this point i'd just set the document root to `/home/myuser/xampp` and edit the xampp config to run as `myuser:myuser`

Comment: Sorry, I was just missing some php extensions. I installed the package `php7.0-xml` and re-installed Laravel and it works a little better, `http://localhost/laravel5/public` displays something but that's a "UnexpectedValueException" (The stream or file "/opt/lampp/htdocs/test-laravel/storage/logs/laravel.log")

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the vendor directory. Run this command in your project directory `composer install`.

Answer (score 0):

This must work as in the documentation. Please read the requirements. Most of the cases are the php version does not support the laravel version installed.

Answer (score -1):

Install composer, you can search for composer in google,
Then you might need to restart your pc, 
And go to your laravel folder in command promot and run composer install command. It will create you the vendor folder and all other required dependancy